# Run a command at the soonest possible 24h time, from a list of times generated automatically from a specified interval in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

Once I get to a certain point within my script, I would like to only continue at the first available opportunity from a specified list of times. This list is automatically generated when given two pieces of information:

- A start time, in 24h format- e.g "05:00"
- A given interval, e.g 7 hours.

For example, the code would take two variables:

```
$StartTime = 05:00
$Interval = 6
```

It would then, beginning at the start time of 05:00 add 6 hours until a set of 4 times is generated (24/6 = 4)

Which would output:

```
05:00
11:00
17:00
23:00
```

The above I have a rough idea on how to do, and have already attempted the second part as follows:

```
$time1 = 05:00
$time2 = 11:00
$time3 = 17:00
$time4 = 23:00

write-host "Waiting for start time..."
start-sleep ((get-date "$time1" -or "$time2" -or "$time3" -or "time4") - (get-date)).TotalSeconds;
write-host "Time reached, code is continuing..."
```

Unfortunately, however, the above doesn't seem to work and I cannot use the -or statement using this method. For even just choosing the most viable of 2 times, let alone automatically generating 4 and then choosing the soonest available one. I feel like there must be a simple, few line answer to this but I cannot think of how to do so. Any help appreciated.

Comment: i would likely do modulus math on the current hour minus the start hour with the modulus set to the interval. something like `($Now.Hour - $Start.Hour) % $Interval`. if that gives `0`, then it is "in the hour". if  you need to be to-the-minute accurate, then add the minutes to the test.

Comment: The issue I'm facing is specifying multiple possible start hours

Comment: if the possible start times are not at regular intervals, then you will have to specify those times and test for each. i would NOT use _time strings_ ... instead, use _datetime objects_ so that you can gracefully compare them.

Comment: This is the plan, I am currently working on the first half and need to work out how to convert get-date -format "HH:mm:ss" 05:00 into a date-time type object.. thanks for your help.

Comment: leave off the `-Format` stuff. [*grin*] good practice in PoSh is to only convert types to strings when there is no other way to do the job. `(Get-Date).Date.AddHours(5)` will give you today at `05:00`. the `.Date` sets the time part to zero [midnite], and after that any added time maps directly to the usual 24 our clock.

Comment: Thank you, I've just asked a more specific question relating to this (see end of this reply) as I became stuck with the first part, I will just have to only "slim" down the date-time result at the last possible moment. I did try using -DisplayHint Time  as I heard this doesn't change it to a string but then I got another issue. Thanks again, I just realised you're that reddit guy too... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63121973/adding-hours-to-date-time-not-working-whilst-using-format-nor-displayhint

Comment: as you can see from their comments, DO NOT change to strings unless you MUST. compare the objects as datetime objects. plus, remember that what you see on screen is NOT the datetime object ... it is the localized date string of that object. that is a common source of confusion. just because the SCREEN display shows "4:05:00 PM` doesn't mean the object is that string ... the datetime object is still a proper datetime object that you can `.AddHours()` to. [*grin*] **_always keep structured objects as such for as long as possible._**