# Adding Hours to Date-Time not working whilst using -format nor-DisplayHint

Tags: powershell, getdate

I would like to use date-time along with either -DisplayHint or -Format to specify a particular time, I am not interested in date.

I would then like to use .AddHours() to add to this specified date or time.

If I do the following:

```
(get-date -date 23:59 -DisplayHint Time).AddHours(+3)
```

The output is 28 July 2020 02:59:00, the time is correct but the -DisplayHint Time is being ignored.

I then tried:

```
$t = get-date -date 23:59 -DisplayHint Time 
$t.AddHours(+3)
```

The -DisplayHint is also ignored.

If I use -format "HH:mm:ss" like so:

```
$t = get-date -date 23:59 -format "HH:mm:ss"
$t.AddHours(+3)
```

It does not work as -format seems to turn it into a string, and the .AddHours no longer works.

How am I supposed to achieve this?

Comment: Don't do `AddHours(+3)` just do `AddHours(3)`, `-DisplayHint Time` doesn't seem to be ignored on my system, maybe try `Get-Date -UFormat %R`. On your last example, try explicitly defining it as type `datetime`, `[DateTime]$t = get-date -date 23:59 -format "HH:mm:ss"`. This will not keep the format though.

Comment: You have both tags PowerShell 3.0 and 4.0, which one are you actually using?

Comment: I would dispense with all the cmdlets and just use the .NET methods. `([DateTime] "23:59").AddHours(3).ToString("HH:mm:ss")`.

Comment: Apologies, I just realised I'm on 5. I thought I was on 4 running it on a system that runs 3.  I'll try what you suggested.

Comment: Thank you Jeroen, this appears to work as I wanted.

Comment: If you explicitly type the var it will output the default for that type.  DisplayHint also works for me on PowerShell 5.1.  `-Format` & `-UFormat` both convert to a string.  You can do the math first then flip to a string like: `$t = (get-date -date 23:59).AddHours(3).ToString( "HH:mm:ss" )`. Also DisplayHint is a setable property, so if it's truly giving you trouble you can try setting it after the fact: `$t.DisplayHint = "Time"`

Answer (score 0):

What you want is just the time with hours minutes and seconds? Then you can just do like this:

```
(get-date -date 23:59).AddHours(+3).ToLongTimeString()
```

That will give:

> 02:59:00